# How to write value in OPCUA server

Tags: python, iot, opc-ua, scada

I'm trying to implement an OPCUA server on the freeopcua library.
SCADA successfully reads data from the server.
Data is also written to the server. But I can not intercept the record in the server itself to send data to the device. I can not understand what method this is implemented in the library. Callback does not process the record.

```
    server.subscribe_server_callback(CallbackType.ItemSubscriptionCreated, create_monitored_items)
server.subscribe_server_callback(CallbackType.ItemSubscriptionModified, modify_monitored_items)
server.subscribe_server_callback(CallbackType.ItemSubscriptionDeleted, delete_monitored_items)
```

Comment: This is only intercepting Subscription-related requests. From what I understood, the question is about the Read service instead?